# Simple assembly level program gives a segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm

I wonder if someone could help me understand why my assembly program is giving me a segmentation fault. (Don't worry, it is a rather short program.)

```
segment .data

    a dq 175
    b dq 4096


segment .text

    global _start

_start:

    mov rax, [a]    ; move *a into rax
    add rax, [b]    ; add *b to rax
    xor rax, rax    ; set to zero
    ret             ; return
```

It should add the values of a and b and then return them as the last exit code when the program terminates, right? So `echo $?` <s>should print `4271` ?</s> It should print 0, due to the `xor`.

But yeah, compiled using: `nasm -f elf64 -l main.lst main.asm -o main.o && ld main.o -o main.exec`

Then run: `./main.exec && echo $?`

Help is greatly appreciated as always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't `ret` from the `_start` label since it wasn't `call`ed.

```
segment .data

    a dq 175
    b dq 4096


segment .text

     global _start

 _start:

    mov rax, [a]    ; move *a into rax
    add rax, [b]    ; add *b to rax
    xor rax, rax    ; set to zero

    mov rdi, rax
    mov al, 60 ; sys_exit
    syscall
```

Try that. (untested!)

Comment: Oh blast, so obvious now

Comment: Why do you move rad into rdi btw? PS: I am on linux, so I think I need to int 0x80 instead of mov al, 60

Comment: No, the high part of `rax` was 0, so `mov al, 60` makes `rax` 60 (sys_exit). `rdi` is the first (only) parameter. 64-bit Linux uses `syscall` instead of `int 0x80`. `int 0x80` will still work in 64-bit code, with the old 32-bit system call numbers (I'm told).

Comment: Is syscall an older method of doing things then? I'm following a (not particularly good actually) book which gives an intro to (specifically) 64bit Linux asm. The convention used there is int 0x80.

Comment: I think `syscall` would be the newer method. `int 0x80` is the older method.